# Converting a multi-dimensional dictionary which contains an array of pandas series to a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have some python code that create a dictionary where the key is followed with the value of a variable length array that contains pandas series.

```
{"key1":[series1,series2,series3], "key2":[series4,series5,series6,..],...}
```

All dataframes contains 2 columns, Word and frequency

I was wondering what will be the most appropriate method to convert this data structure to a csv. In the following format.

```
key, Word, frequency
key1, series1[0][0], series1[0][1]
key1, series1[1][0], series1[1][1]
......
key10, series76[100][0], series76[100][1]  #<-Arbitrary indexes.
```

I have tried iterating through the dictionary and doing it like that. However remnants of the series gets saved to the CSV such as

```
Length: 65, dtype: int64]
```

Therefore ideally I would like to use pandas.to_csv() in this scenario in order to not need to manually parse this data.

Comment: You can only concat pandas objects. However my multi-dimensional strcuture i stored in a dictionary due to the 1 to many relations between the keys and dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with list comprehension:

```
s1 = pd.Series([2,3],index=['aaa','bbb'])
s2 = pd.Series([1,2,3],index=['ccc','fff','ggg'])
s3 = pd.Series([4,5],index=['ddd','eee'])

d = {"key1": [s1, s2], "key2": [s3]}

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'key': k, 'word': x.index, 'freq': x.to_numpy()})
                    for k, v in d.items() 
                    for x in v
                    if isinstance(x, pd.Series)], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    key word  freq
0  key1  aaa     2
1  key1  bbb     3
2  key1  ccc     1
3  key1  fff     2
4  key1  ggg     3
5  key2  ddd     4
6  key2  eee     5

df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error. "'Series' object has no attribute 'assign'"

Comment: Yeah, sorry that's my bad. I accidentally mixed up data frames and series.

Comment: I believe all of my data within the array is series. so when i filter them out nothing is being processed.

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question appropriately. Thanks for helping me identify it!

Comment: Just tried it now! However i am getting the following Attribute error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'"

Comment: Just to let you know, there's a mismatch for the parathesis's used. @jezrael

Comment: the df created only contains 2 columns being the key and the frequency. `key,val
key1,8`

Comment: `the           8
a             7
time          6
in            5
slot          4
             ..
select        1
any           1
one           1
designated    1
slot.         1
Length: 77, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: `{'the': 8, 'a': 7, 'time': 6, 'in': 5, 'slot': 4, 'number': 4, 'of': 4, 'calling': 4, 'apparatus': 4, 'zero': 3, 1, 'requests': 1, 'be': 1, 'made': 1, 'determined': 1, 'dynamically': 1, 'by': 1, 'means': 1, 'feedback': 1, 'control,characterised': 1, 'continuously': 1, 'transmits': 1, 'framelength': 1, 'signals': 1, '(the': 1, 'number)': 1, 'on': 1, 'slot-by-slot': 1, 'basis': 1, 'giving': 1, 'updated': 1, 'available': 1, 'multiple-access': 1, 'select': 1, 'any': 1, 'one': 1, 'designated': 1, 'slot.': 1}`

Comment: @MuratSaglam - Super! Answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# toy data
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["hello", 1], ["world", 1]], columns=["word", "frequency"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["quick", 10], ["brown", 1], ["fox", 3]], columns=["word", "frequency"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([["rice", 9], ["salt", 1], ["sugar", 7]], columns=["word", "frequency"])
data = {"key1": [df1, df2], "key2": [df3]}

# split in keys and values
keys, values = zip(*[(key, value) for key, values in data.items() for value in values])

# use the keys parameter of concat
df = pd.concat(values, keys=keys).droplevel(-1).reset_index().rename(columns={ "index" : "key"})

df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

**Output** *(output.csv)*

```
key,word,frequency
key1,hello,1
key1,world,1
key1,quick,10
key1,brown,1
key1,fox,3
key2,rice,9
key2,salt,1
key2,sugar,7
```

Comment: Just finished executing this, however my output varied and did not display the word, and only did the frequency `key1,2` not `key1,fox,3`